# How to read in the contents of a CSV file as a string?

Tags: javascript, csv

I want to import a CSV file, store its contents as a string, and parse the string into a series of JSON objects. However, I am stuck on how to store CSV contents as a string.

I have the following code for picking a File object from the local file system:

```
var fileList = document.getElementById('loadLocalFilePath').files;
var fileObj = fileList[0];//contains the csv file. 
console.log(fileObj);
```

Which I know works, because it properly logs:

```
File {name: "ChronoVizProject.csv", lastModified: 1606608282054, lastModifiedDate: Sat Nov 28 2020 19:04:42 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 708, …}
```

However, I don't want the details of the File object, but rather the CSV contents as a string.
I read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result and added the following code:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var fileContents = reader.readAsText(fileObj);
console.log(fileContents);
```

However, `fileContents` logs as `undefined`, as does `fileObj.results`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filereader needs to load the file before you can access it. You need to add eventListener with 'load' and then you can access the file inside the eventListener.

```
   const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener('load', function(e) {   
        let fileContents = e.target.result
        console.log(fileContents)
    });
    
    reader.readAsText(fileObj);
```

Comment: Checking my understanding here: `reader.readAsText(fileObj)` does not return anything, but rather sets `e.target.result` to return text? Would it make a difference if we put the last line before the lines adding the event listener?

Comment: That is correct, reader doesn't return anything. The addEventlistener needs added before the readAsText to make it work. If the addEventlistener is after the readAsText, reader isn't listening any events so doesn't do anything.